# RaspberryPi 4 Current issues with multiple power sources and common ground

Tags: pi-4, i2c, pi-gpio, diy

I've been building a tank robot for a while now and in these days I'm struggling with some issues related to insufficient current in my configuration. For instance, some sensors stop working after a while. Could you help me sort it out? At moment I'm powering my rpi4 with a DYM UPS [UPS Shield](https://www.diymore.cc/collections/development-board/products/18650-battery-shield-v8-mobile-power-bank-3v-5v-for-arduino-esp32-esp8266-wifi) which should provide me of 5V and 2.2 A, I've also tried with a Chinese power adapter which should provide up to 3A ( I explicitly want to mention I bought it from aliexpress since I don't believe I'm getting 3A out of it) with the same results. I've bought a usb multimeter to check how much A my rpi absorbs and it should arrive somewhen by the end of this week, meanwhile I was hoping you could have given me some insight.

I don't think it's relevant but the program I wrote, to control the robot, is built on top of cross-compiled Qt 5.15, openCV 4 and raspiCam lib.

My only concern about the schema is that rpi GND which goes to GND 18650 batteries that power the motors (the 2 DC motors and the servo)

At moment I'm using a normal 1080p cam, I was using noIR camera before with 2 IR Leds but the outcome was odd, after few seconds every sensors stopped working and eventually rpi glitched forcing me to reboot it. I would like to find a solution to use the noIR camera with night vision btw..

I'm attaching some photos of my little 'Hope' and its configuration.

[Tank 1](https://ibb.co/TRM5520)
[Tank 2](https://ibb.co/b3w5ZSF)
[Wiring](https://ibb.co/X7dJYcd)

There's a little mistake in the diagram, one of then pin of the H-Bridge is connected wrongly to a gnd pin of the rpi, don't take care of that, it doesn't reflect the real configuration which is fine

I think i've found what's wrong with this setup and is that the 8V ground coming from the 2 18650 batteries in series arrive directly to the i2c multiplexer power line and i believe this is the main cause of my issues. I don't know what i should do to fix it though..

Edit 1: Summarizing, the 3.3v power pin of rpi powers the i2c multiplexer with all the connected sensors, 3 VL53L1-X, a MPU6050, a HMC5883L and a PCA9685. The servo motor and the H-Bridge are powered trough another battery pack consisting of 2 18650 in series whose ground is connected to rpi. Thus rpi has 3 GND tied up together mainly the fan, the i2c multiplexer and the ground from battery pack in series ( plus the ground from the battery shield trough the usb c connector).

Edit 2: Referring to [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63934/raspberry-pi-connected-with-three-stepper-motors-gives-voltage-drop) it seems i might haver encountered the same kind of issue..

Comment: I see no mention of the current draw of the various components.  I see no reason not to draw the obvious conclusion that the power supply is insufficient,

Comment: How could it be unsufficient? I mean, rpi is getting properly powered by the UPS but only draws  0.6-0.7A out of the potential 2.2A. Why does it do like this?

Comment: Learn to use the formatting tools here, please. It's called "Markdown", and you can [view the guide here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/editing-help) - it's very simple.

Comment: Your wiring diagram is not clear. I don't even see a power source for the RPi - where is it? In general, know this: All grounds must be "tied together" - opto-isolaters and transformers are two notable exceptions. Clear up the spaghetti in your diagram, and we'll try to help.

Comment: Sorry if i have not formatted the code properly, btw as i’ve written in the first post, i’m powering the rpi with that battery shield i’ve linked trough the usb c port. Regarding the spaghetti diagram, i’m pretty aware it’s a mess but it’s not that easy to “fix” .. the main logic is that 3.3v power pin of rpi powers the i2c multiplexer with all the connected sensors, 3 VL53L1-X, a MPU6050, a HMC5883L and a PCA9685. The servo motor and the H-Bridge are powered trough another battery pack consisting of 2 18650 in series whose ground is connected to rpi. Thus rpi has 3 GND tied up together

Comment: Mainly the fan, the i2c multiplexer and the ground from battery pack in series ( plus the ground from the battery shield trough the usb c connector). Sorry for double comment but i had reached characters limit

Comment: DO NOT put detail in comments, EDIT your Question. Also if you expect people to look at your Question include the details NOT links.

Comment: *"rpi is getting properly powered by the UPS but only draws 0.6-0.7A out of the potential 2.2A"* -> You got that figure when the Pi was **idle**.  Current consumption is not a constant for the SoC, and it is what sinks most of it.

Comment: So do you think nothing is wrong with the diagram and is it just a problem of power lacking? One thing i wanted to test was getting power for i2c sensors(and multiplexer) from external power source instead of rpi. I connected the i2c multiplexer power to UPS trough exposed power headers ( with a common ground with rpi too). The problem is that commond grounds close the circuit also on my UPS keeping the i2c sensors always on  even though the UPS is off, which is pretty odd :/ I'm quite sure there's mistake in my wiring